# Wireless network suddenly not working on 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 few days ago and it worked fine. I did some tweaks with my ssd and other things including wlan cards power management. I'm afraid i did something wrong while tweaking because tonight when i booted the computer again, wireless network didn't work any more.

I'm not new with ubuntu but I've never learned much about the system so I don't even know what codes to include in this message. Driver is Broadcom BCM43228 and it's ticked in software & updates

iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

EDIT:
I'm not actually sure if the wireless works but I can't find any wi-fi connections. I looked at the BIOS of my computer(Lenovo Thinkpad E530) and I found something odd. Wireless LAN Radio "off" and i couldn't change it on. This has something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not show what you mean in cannot find any wi-fi cinnection. If the problem is what I think it is you shouldn't even see a wi-fi tab.
Try running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

I have a Broadcom to and this is how I fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rat2000's friendly tip didn't help me.
But I installed the Ubuntu 13.04 again and now the wireless works. Not a good solution, if it's an old os, but mine had nothing but few applications. It had something to do with the BIOS "Wireless LAN Radio" because now it turned on. Mysterious? If someone knows, it would be awesome to have the answer here, thinking 'bout the future and other people with the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You appear to post your answer using a different (unregistered) user account. Please register and then get your user account merged with your previous one http://askubuntu.com/contact/user-merge. You will then be able to mark your answer as correct.